# Angular and Bootstrap UI Modal Directive creates duplicate link

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I created a modal directive based off a small tutorial. I've created a basic plunkr of my efforts, my problem is below.

```
<a modal="" name="signin" ng-click="" modal-template="signin" modal-size="sm" 
    modal-color-override="white" class="btn btn-default btn-block ng-isolate-scope">
    <a ng-click="open()" style="color: white;" ng-transclude="" class="ng-binding">
        <span class="ng-scope">Login</span>
    </a>
</a>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XIRoQy?p=preview

The directive creates a secondary a href which causes constant styling issues for bootstrap css because then navbar > li > a turns to navbar > li > a > a.

There are also some button issues, where the link is inside the button, so the click area reduces drastically.

Do you have a recommended way of creating an attribute/element that just adds the modalInstance.open() to the parent element instead of creating a new link inside the parent?

Just so it's clear, I realize that the directive is designed to add the link inside the parent with the template and transclude, but I couldn't find a way around it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add `replace: true` to your directive configuration ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/lACqw4?p=preview)).  I also added `href=""` to your element so the normal link cursor would be used and put a `;` in front of the `open()` call so the `ng-click` code in your index.html would execute as well.

```
app.directive('modal', function($modal){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<a ng-click=";open()" ng-transclude>{{name}}</a>',
    scope: {
```

Html:

```
<a href="" modal name="login" ng-click="navCollapsed = true"
    modal-template="signin" modal-size="sm" >Login</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, the replace does the trick. I did not realize that existed. Thanks again.